# iOS 9 black screen on first launch

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

I have an iOS8 app and after run in Xcode 7.0 (7A218) I got a black screen on first launch. But I see Launch Screen before. Also I see a waring in console:

```
Sep 19 09:36:56  GestureKeyboard[2640] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var imageView : UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var label : UILabel!
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using a storyboard as a launch screen was introduced in Xcode 6 / iOS 8 so I'm guessing that if you're targeting iOS7 you'll need to supply individual images for each device resolution.